# Why is zk rendering a second tbody for a listbox?

Tags: java, html, zk

I'm having a problem where zk 3.6.3 is rendering a second `<tbody>` tag for a `Listbox`. Actually the first rendered `<tbody>` tag is the one that is making me problems. It has it's css style set to `visibility:hidden;height:0px` and Opera 12 and IE 11 are rendering a large white empty space for it. So in the browser I see the table header, this empty space and then the actual rows of the listbox.

The problematic code for zkoss rendering is contained in [`org.zkoss.zkmax.zul.render.ListboxDefault`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.zkoss.zk/zkmax/3.6.3/org/zkoss/zkmax/zul/render/ListboxDefault.java?av=f)) in lines 53-63.

How can I prevent zkoss or browsers from rendering this empty space?

Comment: can you please share some sample code?

Comment: @AlexGreg unfortunately that's a bit difficult as the actual rendering is embedded in a large framework we are using in the project. However having looked again at the code, only thing that should be rendered is the `outerAttrs`. So some really strange things must be going on that these also contain rows from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is always a solution and maybe the "hacking" solution is the best here :

**Class overriding** of that class.

1. Create that package and create that class (exactly the same package and classname).
2. Copy the code from your link to your class.
3. Change the code, I'll suggest try to remove the complete if. => See what result it gives (test al your listboxes!)
4. **When you ever think of upgrading ZK version : Don't forget to remove or update the class !!!**

If removing doesn't help, try to change the style,...

On the other hand, if updating ZK version is possible, you should try that.
The version you use is old, and doesn't support newer browsers.

Comment: Since you have no control in how ZK renders the HTML, I think the best solution is the Java/CSS override approach suggested by @chillworld.

Comment: In the end this goes in the direction I implemented. zk provides a [mechanism](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Development_Essentials/Creating_the_Configuration_Files/The_language-addon) to override rendering. So there's no ugly hacking required.

Answer (score 1):

The first `tbody` contains the list header (no, I don't know why they don't use `thead` for this). If you don't add one to the list, the CSS `visibility:hidden;height:0px` should make it invisible on the screen and that works for me.

My guess is that somewhere in the app, you have CSS rules which override this style. So the next step is to fire up the web developer tools and check which CSS styles are actually applied.

Alternatively, you can give the list box a custom class `setSclass("hiddenheader")` and then use CSS like this:

```
table.hiddenheader tbody:first-child { display: none; }
```

(note: I didn't test this; ZK might add some prefix to the styles so you might have to adjust the code but the example should get you started).